# MVC3, Knockout.js and nested json objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Complete knockout.js newbie here.
I'm having some trouble understanding how knockout.js works. Any help is appreciated.

I have a JSON model that I get back asp.net MVC that looks like somethings like this -

```
var model = [{
"Personal": {"Name" : "Something"},
"Address": [
          {"City" : "Some City"}
          {"City" : "Some Other City"}
          {"City" : "3rd City"}
"Relationships": [
          {"Affiliation" : "Aff1"},
          {"Affiliation" : "Aff2"},
]
]


var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then, in my view I'm trying to do this -

```
<div data-bind="template: {foreach: Address}">
    <span data-bind="value: City"></span>
</div>
```

I get an 'Unable to parse bindings, Address is not defined' error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting a fiddle together which demonstrates your problem (http://jsfiddle.net/) with your exact js code and HTML, then someone can probably help you out.

Comment: Your model is an array, but your view's data-bind is looking for a object with a property "Address". As written, you probably want data-bind="foreach: model.Address". But first, your model should just be a single object, which has an array called Address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean, it "looks something like this"? 
Your javascript model object as written is not a valid one (missing commas, mismatched brackets..). 
It looks like `model` is an array (not an object), and it doesn't make much sense to pass an array to `ko.mapping.fromJS`.

It works fine with valid data (and changing the span's binding to `text` instead of `value`), see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KXhem/16/

Comment: OK. my bad. I was doing this to get data from the MVC model -> var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'; .I replaced it with model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); and it seems to be working. Your answer prompted me to look at the source JSON again, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Going with what anitshok said earlier, here is a cleaned up version that does work, though, the data doesn't come from a server.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'address-template', foreach: Address }">
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="address-template">     
    <span data-bind="text: City"></span><br />
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = {
       Personal: { "Name": "Something" },
       Address: [
         { "City": "Some City" },
         { "City": "Some Other City" },
         { "City": "3rd City"}],
      Relationships: [
         { "Affiliation": "Aff1" },
         { "Affiliation": "Aff2"}]
    };

    ko.applyBindings(model); 
</script>
```

What your code seemed to be missing is the call to the template, the wrapper of the template and a model which had some bad markup in it. You should be able to get started from this.

Here is a link the [knockout mappings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), and the [knockoutjs templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). I'm using knockoutjs 2.1.0, so you might be looking at an older example.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Comment: I saw antishok's response first, but I want to say thanks to you too. Have an upvote +1.